# hibernate multiple queries executing

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

I am having a model User and having id and other properties in it.

```
public class User{
      int id;
      .....

      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="id")
      private UserLocation userLocationObj;

}
```

UserLocation is the model class and like the UserLocation there are more 5-6 properties with same annotations to make the association with the User class.

In the UserLocation model class and other model classes also I did the one to one mapping with the user class .

And also other properties along with their getter and setter. And when I am trying to getting the object of User class by using id it is executing n number of queries and then showing stackoverflow error . Why so ??

My User table Structure is :
User

```
+----------------------+-----
| Field                | Key|
+----------------------+-----
| id                   | PRI| 
| userName             |    |             
| first_name           |    |             
| middle_name          |    |            
| last_name            |    |            
| dateOfBirth          |    |            
| gender               |    |            
| city                 |    |            
| email                |    |
+----------------------+----+

My UserLocation table Structure is :
UserLocation
+-----------------++-----
| Field           | Key |
+-----------------+------
| id              | PRI |
| user_id         |     |
| current_city    |     |
| current_country |     |
| latitude        |     |
| longitude       |     |
| iso_location    |     |
+-----------------+-----+
```

UserId in the UserLocation is the id of the Users table .

Thanks

Comment: can you add the `User` and `UserLocation` table structure pls?

Comment: I have added the table structure please check for the structure and let me know . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is connected to the name of your column:
You are telling hibernate that `@JoinColumn(name="id")` : this means that in the table `User` there is a field named `id`, that joins in the table `UserLocation`, which is not what is your database structure.

You have instead the object `User` in the `UserLocation` table, so this is represented by

```
public class UserLocation{
      int id;
      .....

      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
      @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
      private User user;

}
```

Then, you can let the `User` class know that it has connected the `UserLocation` class with this:

```
public class User{
      int id;
      .....

      @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user_id")
      private UserLocation userLocationObj;

}
```

The `JoinColumn` annotation indicates that the class is the **owner** of the relation, so in this case the owner is `UserLocation`, whereas the `mappedBy` represent the other side of the linking.